# Adding table in Javascript returns null

Tags: javascript

Im trying to do tables with js and to my surprise it isnt a walk in the park if you know what i mean, any how my code keep returning null when I know there is info to be spat out.

the html struture should be

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>info here info here</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>info here info here</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

instead im getting

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>info here info here</th>
    <th>info here info here</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

this is the JS i am using and I also added the full code to fiddle totalF is returning null

```
 function totalF(){
    var body = document.getElementById('body')[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');    
    var tblbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    var tndiv = document.getElementById('tdcontainer');

    for (var j = 0; j < payments; j++){
        var row = document.createElement('tr');

        temp=round(principal);
        while(temp>0){    
            if(tndiv != null){
                var cell = document.createElement('td');
                var ndiv =  round(temp);

                cell.appendChild(ndiv);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            tblBody.appendChild(row);
            temp-=monthly;
            }
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        body.appendChild(tbl);
        tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: sorry added in the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Q4eCa/

Comment: What fiddle? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: So...what's returning `null`?

Comment: `document.getElementById('body')` – what element has the id body? And why do you perform getElementById and then take an index? There can only be one element with one id.

Comment: how/where is `principal` defined? You never change that inside your totalF() function.

Comment: And `payments` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry all forgot to add js fiddle link. Please check the link now and more down votes, it was a simple mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var body = document.body;
```

You were using `document.getElementById('body')[0]`... That will not work because getElementById does not return an array, it returns a single element.  Event if you didn't have the `[0]`, it would only work if you actually add an id of "body" to the body element...

(see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4eCa/2/)

You also used both `tblbody` and `tblBody`... You need to pick one because javascript is case sensitive.

This also throws errors:

```
var ndiv =  round(temp);
cell.appendChild(ndiv);
```

because you cannot "appendChild" a string onto a DOM node.  Try this instead:

```
var ndiv =  round(temp);
cell.innerHTML = ndiv;
```

That will get you most of the way there.  At that point the tables are getting created and you just have bugs in the "calculate" function.

Comment: actually I did try that but it didnt work, I added a id to the body, and even changed it to getElementbyTagname but it didnt return anything. I added in the js fiddle link, Sorry i forgot to added it before, i didnt think everyone would be so hostel about it and down vote me a bunch of times :(

Comment: BTW, you should open up your javascript console. That is where all these bugs are revealed. If you tell us which browser you are using for testing then we can help you do that and you'll have a much easier time figuring this stuff out.

Comment: I know im sorry, i was using firebug, i meant to add it in but typing out the message and getting it together, i got side tracked, simple mistake, thank you for you help.